# yolov3を使おうとするとkerasとtensorflowが関係する様々なバグが起こります。yolov3に適したkerasとtensorflowのバージョンは何ですか？

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
python yolo_video.py --image
```

これを実行するときに出たエラーはライブラリのバージョンが原因のようなのでkerasとtensorflowのバージョンを変えて試してみましたがうまくいきません。

yolov3公式のページにも適したバージョンについて書いていませんでした。

自分の環境はWindows10、anacondaでpython==3.8.11,tensorflow==2.5.0,keras==2.2.4です。

皆さんの実行できた時のバージョンを教えてもらえると嬉しいです。

追記
keras-yolo-masterというものを使っていますが
keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.pyからエラーがいくつか出ました
その時のエラーの一部がこれです

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yolo_video.py", line 73, in <module>
    detect_img(YOLO(**vars(FLAGS)))
  File "C:\Users\your\OneDrive\デスクトップ\keras-yolo3-master\yolo.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.sess = K.get_session()
  File "C:\Users\your\anaconda3\envs\yolo_you\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 180, in get_session
    default_session = tf.get_default_session()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_session'
```

これらは主にtf.get_default_session()をtf.compat.v1.get_default_session()に変えれば動作するのでtensorflow_backend.pyを

```
tf_upgrade_v2 --infile in.py --outfile out.py
```

のコードを使って変更しました
しかしまだまだtensorflowかkerasのバージョンが違うから起きたのであろうエラーが発生します。例えば

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\your\OneDrive\デスクトップ\keras-yolo3-master\yolo.py", line 70, in generate
    self.yolo_model = load_model(model_path, compile=False)
  File "C:\Users\your\anaconda3\envs\yolo_you\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "C:\Users\your\anaconda3\envs\yolo_you\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 224, in _deserialize_model
    model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

このエラーも解決法はわかりませんが
一つ一つのエラーを潰していくよりtensorflowとkerasのバージョンを変えたほうがいいのではないかと思って質問しています。

Comment: この記事あたりでは？ [YOLOのオリジナルデータ学習手順 #3-1 YOLOv3 Keras版実装](https://qiita.com/tfukumori/items/d1f79078803d8a7fe103)

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　最適な回答をするために、まずは質問者さんの情報を教えてください。Keras が必要になっているということは、使ってらっしゃるのは https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3 ですか？　それとも別のものですか？　yolo_video.py は正確に https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/e6598d13c703029b2686bc2eb8d5c09badf42992/yolo_video.py でしょうか。（以上は、環境違いで回答が行き違うのを避けるために知りたいです。）また、具体的にどのようなメッセージのエラーが出ましたか？（[XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/19110)に陥るのを避けるために知りたいです。）質問を [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: nekketsuuu さんが貼った [keras-yolo3](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3) であれば、README の下の方にテストした環境のバージョン情報が書かれているので、(多少古いけど) まずはそれらに合わせてみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: @アランロネルタ keras-yolo-master がインターネットに公開されているものであれば URL が欲しいです。検索しても見つかりませんでした。keras-yolo3-master であれば https://github.com/wuwenfu5/keras-yolo3-master というのは見つかりましたがそこまで使われているものでは無さそうです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu　おそらく私がダウンロードしたのはkeras-yolo3と同じものです。なぜかはわかりませんが、ダウンロードした時にフォルダ名が変わっていたようです。

Comment: ではまずダウンロードやインストールの段階から、ひとつずつ指差し確認しつつやると良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

教えてくれた方々ありがとうございます。
公式のバージョンに変えてもエラーが出るので、yolo_video.pyが使えるようになったわけではないですが、実行すべき環境はわかったため、このバージョンで頑張ってみようと思います。